# Disable My account edit addresses for a specific user role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-roles

How can I completely disable the address section in "my account" for a user role in woocommerce?

I'm trying to remove the ability to edit customer addresses for a specific user role. Right now it's just a copy of woocommerce customer.
This user role is a special group and I don't want theme to be able to edit their billing and shipping details, i.e. access address section of "my account".

I know I could go thru the templates and remove these fields if user is that role. I'm just thinking there must be some hook or filter that could disable this based on user role, or alternatively how to disable "edit account" completely in the user role (so for a woocommerce customer that has only read access I would also want to remove the ability for that user to edit their own information).

Any help or reference for this is greatly appreciated! I've googled and stacked around overflow but can't find anything clear.

Comment: Please refer to this Question. your answer is here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434418/hiding-div-from-menu-based-on-user-role-capabilities-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434418/hiding-div-from-menu-based-on-user-role-capabilities-wordpress)