# Hiding DIV from menu based on user role / capabilities Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hide

I have a wordpress site with 2 user roles, customer and vendor. I want to hide the Vendor Dashboard from the menu bar from Customers. The code for this theme is in the header-aside.php file so a plugin won't work to hide this element. I have tried the following code which hides this from everyone, not just customers, so I'm not sure what I have wrong here.

```
     <?php if (current_user_can(‘read’)) { ?>
        <div class="dashboard-icon">
            <a id="header-button" href="/creator-dashboard/" class="header-button boss-tooltip" data-tooltip="<?php _e( 'Creator Dashboard', 'onesocial' ); ?>"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Note I have the capability 'read' in there as a test since I am unable to get it to show. But the actual capability a vendor has is 'edit_products'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the user roles inside the [WP_User](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) object, which is returned by the function [wp_get_current_user ()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).
So you may show Dashboard only for Vendor by that code:

```
<?php 
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'vendor', $user->roles ) ) {
?>
    <!-- Any HTML what you need to hide from "Customers" and show for "Vendor" -->
    <div>Vendor Dashboard</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi I'm not sure how to add the div inside this code, it keeps breaking the site. Sorry my php knowledge is still learning!

Comment: @pathosmusic div is for example. Just replace the `<div> Vendor Dashboard </ div>` with HTML that you need to hide from "Customers"

Comment: Thx for the help Rimarx, I tried this but the site just displays white with only the top menu and nothing else. Could it be the other data-tooltip="<?php _e( 'Creator Dashboard', 'onesocial' ); ?>" that is messing this up?

Comment: @pathosmusic I edited reply. try to copy and check now

Comment: Rimarx you are a life saver, this works great! I voted your answer as accepted!